# How to write a method which takes int args either 0 or 1 and gives output 1 or 0

Tags: java, logic

I want to write a method which takes int args either 0 or 1 and gives output 1 or 0. Means if I give input as 0 it should return 1 and if input is 1 is should return 0. But the problem is I cant use if else, ternary operator or any collection.

Method should behave like this:

```
public int myMethod(int i)
{
    return j; // if i is 0 then j should be 1 and vice versa.
}
```

Comment: What should it do for any other input?

Comment: no input is fixed either 0 or 1.  and if input is 0 then output should be 1.  if input is 1 then output should be 0

Comment: Well the input to that method *isn't* fixed - so you need to think about what you *will* do if the input isn't 0 or 1. There's nothing to stop someone from calling `myMethod(2)`. You might explicitly say that the result is undefined in that case (that it can be anything) but you should at least think about it.

Comment: @jon it was a interview question

Comment: Then it would have been a good idea to ask for requirements at that point.

Comment: ok, next time i will remember

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return 1-input;
```

input is the value coming in.

Comment: its working fine. thanks a lot. +1 for ur answer. websites restrict me to accept ur answer. i will accept it after 6 minutes

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

`return Math.abs(i-1);`

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by Saraubh, also do check for input before return.

```
public int myMethod(int i)
{
    if (i != 0 && i != 1)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input should be 0 or 1");
    }
    return 1 - i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public int myMethod(int i){
    return 1^i;
}
```

This will do an exclusive or operation. if i = 0 -> returns 1, if i = 1 returns 0. Assuming that the input i is either 0 or 1 ...

Answer (score 2):

The question is interesting. Here are other possible ways: (in fact a bit impractical and expensive, just for your interest...)

```
public int myMethod(int i)
{
    return (int)Math.asin(Math.cos(i));
}
```

or

```
public int myMethod(int i)
{
    return ("10").indexOf(i+"");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public int myMethod(int i)
    {
        if (i != 0 && i != 1)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input should be 0 or 1");
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(new String(("10").charAt(i)));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest solution:

```
public int myMethod(int i)
{
    return 1-i;
}
```

or

```
public int myMethod(int i)
{
    int j = 0;
    if (i == 0) {
        j = 1;
    }
    return j;
}
```

Comment: you cannot use, if and else; thus second solution ruled out :)